# HTMLNode.Name containing pound sign in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have code using the Html Agility Pack.  There is a line that compares the name of an HTML node to a string containing a pound sign.  Does that make sense?

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node;

...

if (node.Name == "#text") ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.
Is is a Text Node. Because it is not contained by a `<` and a `>` .

Comment: HtmlNode..::..HtmlNodeTypeNameText Field -> Gets the name of a text node. It is actually defined as '#text'.   It is defined in .chm documentation. Give the documentation a try first. ;)